# Знаки вопроса при выводе текста в Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

Например, если написать: System.out.println("Привет!"), то на выходе будет это недоразумение: ������! Мучаюсь с этим уже довольно долго, где я только не ставил кодировку UTF-8 - все бесполезно. Шрифт стандартный (Consolas), он поддерживает русский язык. Ставил и другие шрифты - результат тот же. Как я понимаю, судя по форумам, подобная проблема есть на всех языках, кроме вездесущего английского. Как это решить? В intellij idea подобной проблемы нет. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте `PrintWriter consoleOut = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "Cp866"));
consoleOut.println("Привет!");`

Comment: если это под виндой, то по умолчанию в консоли не utf-8, а cp866

Comment: либо перед выводом отправить в консоль команду `chcp 65001`, чтобы перевести её в utf-8 режим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лень писать, ->Run Configurations -> Common-> Encoding[[image: Конфигурация проекта][1]]

Comment: Вчера я тоже к этому решению пришел (прочел на одном из форуме). Тем не менее спасибо вам. Я думаю многим ваш ответ пригодится. Может знаете, как сделать так, чтобы эта кодировка применялась как стандартная ко всем проектам сразу?

Comment: поменять  кодировку в WorkSpace ,но там после  каждого обновления кодировку  восстанавливается на по умолчанию